# How to publish online an Angular project? index.html file management

Tags: angular, typescript, publish, filezilla

I have an angular project of a website. This website communicates with a database online using PHP.

I upload the PHP files and the communication with DB works.
Now I'm trying to upload the angular frontend but I have some problems.

If I try to search my website with example.com I get this error: "Forbidden, You don't have permission to access this resource."

This is what I done:

- I opened cmd.exe inside my angular project and I compiled it using *ng build --prod*
- I took the content of the *dist* folder created and I uploaded it on my *Aruba* space with *FileZilla*
- I uploaded file .htaccess with this content:

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]

Probably my problem is related to the index.html.
The first page of the website should be login.component.html, my index.html never changed during my coding.

This is my index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my app-routing.modules.ts:

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginRegisterComponent } from './login-register/login-register.component';
import { NuovoPiattoComponent } from './admin/nuovo-piatto/nuovo-piatto.component';
import { VotiComponent } from './admin/voti/voti.component';
import { NuovoIngredienteComponent } from './admin/nuovo-piatto/nuovo-ingrediente/nuovo-ingrediente.component';
import { VotoComponent } from './home/voto/voto.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    //first page
    path: '',
    component: LoginRegisterComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin/nuovo-piatto',
    component: NuovoPiattoComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin/voti',
    component: VotiComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin/nuovo-piatto/nuovo-ingrediente',
    component: NuovoIngredienteComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home/voto',
    component: VotoComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I didn't even touch the app.component.html / .ts files.

Can you help me?

Comment: firstly, what hosting are you using? Is that hosting allowing public connections?

Comment: when you say "the content of the *dist* folder ", you really need copy all the folder where you has the "index.html" -see that if in your angular.json, you has, e.g. `"outputPath": "dist/my-app"` you should copy the folder 'dist/my-app' in the root of your "server"

Comment: @user3875913 yes are allowed. My hosting is online using Aruba on a Linux based machine

Comment: @Eliseo yes I have dist/Angular. I have the main folder called "MyProject", inside that I have PHP and Angular folders. I thought that I had to upload only the contents of the folder dist